# Can I execute UPDATE and INSERT for one SQL merge match condition?

Tags: sql-server, merge

I'm writing a merge statement for a table that has an int column used for bit flags. The idea is that two different flags can share the same row as long as all the other columns are equal. Otherwise each flag gets an individual row. It's possible a row can be shared initially, but the source data can change for one flag requiring a separate row.

This query is what I need to happen, but I can't have both UPDATE and INSERT as written. Is there a way to make this work? Or some other way to solve my problem?

```
DECLARE @flag int = 128;
MERGE target_table
USING ( select * from source_table ) as source_table
ON <key value>
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT <other values equal> 
     AND ( field1 & @flag ) != 0 AND field1 != @flag THEN

    UPDATE SET field1 = ( field1 & ~@flag )

    INSERT ( flagField, <columns> ) 
    VALUES ( @flag, <values> )

;
```

Comment: Your syntax for merge statement requires serious attention.

Comment: @M.Ali ok? It's a rough sample for illustration. What do you want me to do about it?

Comment: It is a pretty rough example, there is no `ON` clause the condition on which target and source tables should be merged, your update clause seems way out of order. Post your actual attempt, so people can actually see how far you are from the actual solution and if possible show some sample data and desired output.

Comment: @M.Ali My actual query is enormous and contains enough identifying info I don't want post it. The update and insert statements are the part I'm concerned about here, and represent what I'm actually doing. Everything else is just for show and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think to do it is to split the source rows that need to be split into two rows, a update row and an insert row. I used `CROSS APPLY` to do this. You could then filter it so that only the rows that will be split have the insert row. Then add a join condition so that the insert row doesn't match.

Be aware that there are warnings about using the `MERGE` `ON` clause as a filter, but I don't believe it's problematic in this case because I'm using it as a join condition, not as a filter condition.

Below is the script I used for testing. It takes rows that have `val2` = 0 and splits them to two rows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [TestTableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [val1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [val2] [int] NOT NULL
)

GO

TRUNCATE TABLE TestTable
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable(val1, val2)
VALUES
    (1,0)
    ,(2,1)
    ,(2,2)
    ,(3,0)
GO


DECLARE @SplitTable TABLE (TestTableId INT, val1 INT)

INSERT INTO @SplitTable
SELECT
    TestTableId, val1
FROM
    TestTable
WHERE
    val2 = 0

SELECT * FROM @SplitTable

;
WITH SplitRows AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        @SplitTable
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (1),(2)
        )AS Split (RowNum)
)
MERGE TestTable Trg
USING (SELECT * FROM SplitRows) AS Src
    ON Trg.TestTableId = Src.TestTableId
        AND Src.RowNum = 1
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE
SET
    val2 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (
    val1
    ,val2
)
VALUES (
    Src.val1
    ,2
)
;

SELECT * FROM TestTable
```